# Issue. Jackson in Spring not throws any exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a code like:

```
public class BigDecimalDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<BigDecimal> {
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern
        .compile("^([1-9]+[0-9]*)((\\.)[0-9]+)?$");
    private static final String MESSAGE = "must be a number in format (99 or 99.99)";
    private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

    @Override
    public BigDecimal deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) 
                  throws IOException, JsonProcessingException 
    {
        BigDecimal result = null;
        JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);
        String text = node.asText();

        if (text != null && !text.equals(EMPTY_STRING)) {
            Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(text);

            if (matcher.matches()) {
                result = new BigDecimal(text);
            } else {
                throw new ApplicationException(MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Nothing happens when this method throws ApplicationException or other type of exception.

**`Where this exception catches? And why there is no stacktraces in the console?`**
p.s. im trying to handle this exception in the **`@ControllerAdvice class (@ExceptionHandler(ApplicationException.class) method)`**..but nothing happens.

MessageConverter config:

```
public void configureMessageConverters(
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    converters.add(converter);
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```

ContollerAdvice:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ApplicationException.class)
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleWrongRequest(
        RuntimeException exception, WebRequest request) {
    ApplicationException applicationException = (ApplicationException) exception;

    Error error = new Error();
    error.setField(EMPTY);
    error.setMessage(applicationException.getRootMessage());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    return handleExceptionInternal(exception, error, headers,
            HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, request);
}
```

Where Spring handles Jackson exceptions?

Comment: it would be nice if you could provide a runnable example of this. there's no way for us to know what kind of setup you have with @Exceptionhandlers and such.

Comment: I added piece of my configuration and @ExceptionHandler.